# Using gcc attributes with C++11 attributes syntax

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, attributes

I was trying to use the [GCC attributes](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html#Function-Attributes) with the [C++11 syntax](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes). For example something like this:

```
static void [[used]] foo(void)
{
    // ...
}
```

But I get the following:

```
warning: ‘used’ attribute ignored [-Wattributes]
static void [[used]] foo(void)
            ^
```

Why is the attribute ignored? Is it possible to use GCC attributes as C++ attributes?

Comment: Nothing is wrong. What makes you believe anything is wrong?

Comment: @KerrekSB _"What makes you believe anything is wrong?"_ That there's a warning applied about it of course. Why is it so?

Comment: @KerrekSB : the fact that the attribute is being ignored

Comment: @KerrekSB _"I get that from my wife every day."_ Those nagging daily annoyers :) ...

Comment: @KerrekSB : How do I do for that attribute not being ignored?

Comment: Well, the support for attributes is implementation defined, so that's not by itself a problem. Maybe GCC doesn't support that attribute. Never mind that it supports a separate and distinct set of attributes as an extension via `__attribute__`. I guess the core of the question is whether GCC allows GCC attributes to be used as C++ attributes?

Comment: @AndresTiraboschi _"How do I do for that attribute not being ignored? "_ Use another toolchain that doesn't ignore it.

Comment: @AndresTiraboschi Every toolchain will ignore it, because that's the correct behaviour - such thing doesn't exist. If you need such non-standard attributes, you need to stick with compiler-specific solutions. I don't think GCC allows its `__attributes__` to be used with C++ 11 `[[...]]`syntax.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
[[gnu::used]] static void foo(void) {}
```

First, the attribute can only appear in specific places, otherwise you get:

```
x.cc:1:13: warning: attribute ignored [-Wattributes]
 static void [[gnu::used]] foo(void) {}
             ^
x.cc:1:13: note: an attribute that appertains to a type-specifier is ignored
```

Second, `used` is not a standard warning, so it gets hidden in a proprietary namespace `gnu::`.

Answer (score 4):

There is no `[[used]]` attribute in C++ 11, that's why it's being ignored. **(*)**

There is gcc-specific `__attribute__((used))`, that can be applied to static object or function definitions. It tells compiler to emit definitions, even if that symbol seems to be unused at all - in other words, it makes you sure, that such symbol will be present in result object file.

---

**(*)** It needs to be ignored, because standard allows implementations to define additional, implementation-specific attributes. So there is no point in treating unknown attributes as an error (similar case: `#pragma` directives).

---

Some additional info:

> Attributes provide the unified standard syntax for implementation-defined language extensions, such as the GNU and IBM language extensions `__attribute__((...))`, Microsoft extension `__declspec()`, etc.

And, probably the most important part:

> Only the following attributes are defined by the C++ standard. All other attributes are implementation-specific.
>
> - `[[noreturn]]`
> - `[[carries_dependency]]`
> - `[[deprecated]]` *(C++14)*
> - `[[deprecated("reason")]]` *(C++14)*

Source: [attribute specifier sequence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes).

Answer (score 2):

gcc attributes are not the same as the attributes introduced in C++11.

`used` is a gcc-specific attribute and should be introduced using the gcc attribute syntax, `__attribute__((used))`. There is no `[[used]]` attribute in standard C++, so gcc will simply ignore it.

Comment: Well, the C++ standard doesn't limit the number of supported attributes. It predefines a few (like `[[noreturn]]`), but it allows other attributes to exist with implementation-defined semantics.

Comment: @KerrekSB, that is interesting. Are there no reserved words or conversions similar to how it is with (library defined) user defined literals?

Comment: @JohanLundberg: I don't think so. See the link I added.